# MYSQL import: port a big list of names into mysql table column. An easy way?

Tags: mysql, import

I have a txt file with tons of complex names I want to insert into my sql table named cred_insurances. The table is currently blank. Each line should be one record and the name should be in the column called ProviderName. My text file is like this:

```
Alabama Medicaid
Alaska Medicaid
Arizona Medicaid (AHCCCS)
Arkansas Medicaid
California Medicaid
Colorado Medicaid
Colorado Medicare
Connecticut Medicaid
Delaware Medicaid
Florida Medicaid
ETC...BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

I was thinking of doing some sort of replace function on the text file that might be able to put the proper sql syntax before and after each name so that I could paste it all at the prompt, but that seems quite much. There must be an easier way to do this.

I think that a single command for each line would be thus:

```
INSERT INTO cred_insurances (ProviderName) values ("Alabama Medicaid");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work, assuming your lines are separated by a CRLF (\r\n):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.txt' INTO TABLE cred_insurances
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (ProviderName);
```

Comment: This worked except for that I had to insert "local" before "INFILE" in order to avoid a permissions issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE cred_insurances
(ProviderName)

(you may need, to tinker with parameters if it ignores stuff after the space, but this should work)

Answer (score 0):

There sure is an easier way to batch import data from a text file, much faster than lots of inserts as well.

Something along these lines
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE cred_insurances;

Have a look at the documentation to get the correct syntax if you use tab or space delimited etc.

[LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)